# Does the changing the integration variable affects the derivative inside?

Tags: integration, derivatives

If $x$ and $t$ are two real independent variables and $f(x,t)$ is a real function and I have the derivative of integral

$$\displaystyle\int_{t_0}^{t_e}\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}\,dt$$

Then am I allowed to change the variable $t$ to a variable which relates $t$ and $x$ such as $\bar{t}=\dfrac{t}{x^3}$? If so, how does it change the integrand?

As such, can I proceed?

$$\displaystyle\int_{\bar{t_0}}^{\bar{t_e}}x^3\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}\,d\bar{t} \stackrel{?}{=} x^3\displaystyle\int_{\bar{t_0}}^{\bar{t_e}}\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}\,d\bar{t}$$

where $\bar{t_0}=\dfrac{t_0}{x^3}$ and $\bar{t_e}=\dfrac{t_e}{x^3}$.

This is about my thesis, $x$ and $\sqrt[3]{t}$ are length scales.

Comment: that depends on whether you are redefining the function in terms of the new variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The derivative will be affected if you work with it in an abstract way, without resolving it into an expression in terms of $x$ and $t$. Here is a simple example:

Suppose $f(x,t) = x^4t$. Then $\partial f/\partial x = 4x^3t$. But after the switch to $\overline t = t/x^3$, the function will have to change to $\overline f(x, \overline t) = x^7 \overline t$ and the derivative will have a new "meaning" $\partial \overline f/\partial x = 7x^6\overline t$.

This happens because a partial derivative is always defined with respect to some of the variables kept constant, and the change of variable affects that. But if you resolve you partial derivative into an expression **before** the switch, it should be fine.

So if, in this example, you just want to evaluate
$$ \int_{a}^{b} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} dt = \int_a^b 4x^3tdt = 4x^3\int_a^btdt = 2x^3(b^2-a^2) $$
then
$$ \int_a^b 4x^3tdt = \int_{a/x^3}^{b/x^3}4x^3(\overline t x^3)(x^3)d(d\overline t) = 4x^9\int_{a/x^3}^{b/x^3}\overline t d\overline t $$ will give you the same result.

On the other hand, it would be wrong to claim, that
$$ \int_a^b \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} dt = \int_{a/x^3}^{b/x^3}(x^3)\frac{\partial \overline f}{\partial x} d\overline t $$
**if** the partial derivative in the second integral is eveluated with respect to the "new" function $\overline f(x, \overline t) = x^7 \overline t$.

I am assuming in all this that you want the change of variable to preserve the **value** of the function, so that $f(x, t) = \overline f(x, \overline t)$.

Comment: But what annoys me is I have just done a simple right mathematical operation. It might not make sense (the integrand) but still does not violate rules. What rule is broken in that procedure?

Comment: @Reza the question is whether you are working with that partial derivative abstractly - without a specific expression for it, as if you were trying to prove some general theorem - or you are simply evaluating it. In the latter case, you won't have to worry. I'll edit the answer to clarify.

Comment: @Reza I updated the answer, but it just occurred to me that I might have taken the discussion in a direction that you did not intend. The equal sign in your post that has a question mark on top of it does hold. I was really discussing whether the expression on its left is the same as the one you started from, at the very beginning of your question.

Comment: @ Nick Your answer was very clear. Very simple, when I change the variable of the integration, I need to be careful of the expression of the partial derivative since the varaibles are reorganized. Just in case it might intrigue you, the function f is representing the value of the pressure at remote and x is a length scale at the center and t is the volume that x creates.
Thank you for your help.